# How to execute two commands simultaneously in C

Tags: c

Thank you all for the advices and proposed answers, i finally solved it myself and this is how it should look:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "+") == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    argv[i] = NULL;

    if (fork() == 0) {
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
        exit(0);
    }

    if (fork() == 0) {
        execvp(argv[i+1], &argv[i+1]);
        exit(0);
    }

    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);

    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: I'll suggest you start with reading `exec(3)` man pages. Also think about what will be the size of the `prog1` (how many *characters* can it hold?). Lastly, I'd suggest you to skip the `fork` part and just print out `prog1` and `prog2` at various places to see what your code is doing.

Comment: I'm afraid there is a lot wrong here.  The loop checking for `"+"` won't stop properly if there's no `+` on the command line, the `prog1[]` and `prog2[]` buffers do not put a NULL pointer at the end of their lists too. All of these are going to cause the program to fail badly. I also don't see how `prog2[]` is getting set at all. Recommend that you turn on compiler warnings and dive in to understand what they're telling you about the code.

Comment: If OP's code is really far from his goal is not a good reason for downvoting, IMHO. Yexo : follow @gst advice.

Comment: `can't keep` *what* is it you *can't keep*?

Comment: Hello @Yexo: can you tell us if you're using `fork()` and `exec()` because of a specific requirement, or might alternate solutions work?  A solution that built up another command line and used `fork` and `system` might work as well.

Comment: Your updated version is so, so much better!  It works now, right?

Answer (score 1):

Building on the OP code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i =1 ;

    // Argument list for first call
    i1 = i ;
    char *prog1[argc];
    while (strcmp(argv[i], "+") != 0) {
            prog1[i-i1] = argv[i];
            i++;
    }
    prog[i-1] = NULL ;

    // Argument list for second call
    int i2 = i ;
    char *prog2[argc];
    whlie ( i < argc ) {
        prog2[i-i2] = argv[i] ;
    } ;
    prog2[i-i2] = NULL ;

    pid_t pid1 = fork() ;
    if ( pid1 == 0) {
        execvp(prog1[0], prog1);
        exit(0);
    }

    pid_t pid2 = fork() ;
    if ( pid2 == 0) {
        execvp(prog2[0], prog2);
        exit(0);
    }

    // Wait for all childs
    int status ;
    while ( wait(&status) ) { } ;

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What happens if the user runs the program without a `+` parameter?

Comment: I would comment that our goal is SO is to help the OP solve problems he can not solve by himself. The above code will NEVER qualified for production system - there is no validation of input, no error checks on ANY function, and inefficiencies. Overtime, with practice, and with occasional help from SO community, the OP will become a master of those issues.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Forking works fine for parallel execution, but I'd recommend using threads instead. Either use a higher level threading API or use the standard for POSIX, pthreads. When you compile just make sure you link with `-lpthread`.

Something like:

```
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct
{
  const char* command;
} thread_arg;

void* command_thread(void* v_arg)
{
  thread_arg* arg = (thread_arg*) v_arg;
  system(arg->command);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  pthread_t thread0, thread1;
  thread_arg arg0, arg1;

  /* specify arguments */
  arg0.command = [command to execute on thread 0];
  arg1.command = [command to execute on thread 1];

  /* create threads */
  pthread_create(&thread0, NULL, command_thread, &arg0);
  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, command_thread, &arg1);

  /* wait for threads to complete */
  pthread_join(thread0, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

would work, if arguments were properly delimited.

If you don't have to use `+` to delimit two arguments I'd just use double quotes when calling the program and then just take `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` as the commands.

If this is an assignment and you must use `+` to delimit, then you should check if `+` is even in the list of arguments.

```
int p = 0;
unsigned int i = 0;

/* check if any argument is '+' */
for(unsigned int j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
  if(strcmp(argv[j], "+") == 0) {
    p = 1;
    i = j;
  }
}

/* feel free to resize as needed */
char command0[256];
char command1[256];

if(p) {
  /* plus found, separate strings */

  /* get string before plus */
  for(unsigned int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
    strcat(command0, argv[j]);
    strcat(command0, " ");
  }

  /* get string after plus, i + 1 as i is zero based */
  for(unsigned int j = i + 1; j < argc; j++)
  {
    strcat(command1, argv[j]);
    strcat(command1, " ");
  }
}
```

`strcat` just copies the second string argument onto the end of the first, while also assuring the command is properly zero terminated.

Comment: Using threads is certainly a way to solve this problem, but I'm not sure that offering a a pthreads-based answer to an OP who is struggling with the bare aspects of C is really helping them much.

Comment: ... but the OP would do well to learn from the way better string handling here.

Comment: Either method of solving the 'simultaneous' aspect works, I just prefer using threads. C isn't exactly a forgiving language when it comes to threading, or really anything for that matter.

Comment: Given that each thread will have to fork a process (`ls` or `grep`), there is really no value in mixing threads here. The parallel processing will occur at the process level, not at the thread level

Comment: "I just prefer using threads." I also gave the disclaimer that using threads is an alternate solution.

Comment: Concatenating the argument list (and then executing them with system) will not work for any command that has special characters in the arguments. For example: `grep "a b" file1` will result in interpreting b as a file name, and not as part of the pattern.

Comment: When calling the main program the user would have to escape the special characters.